# Developing within VMs across multiple machines(Virtual box)

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, development

Recently I've developed a need to work within a few virtual machines. If I want to work on a different machine I've actually been copying it back and forth and it is a pain to do and causes issues.

What I am really looking for is an efficient method to launch and operate one VM from multiple Windows clients.

I see there is a remote display option for Virtual Box which I have not tried yet but wanted to get an opinion or two.

Comment: May I recommend [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/)

Comment: Vagrant looks very cool. I'm going to try it out.

Comment: Glad I could Help...